neutral-description が versus は after noun phrases quantified by 多く and 大部分
Susumu Kuno (The Structure of the Japanese Language, p. 58) when discussing neutral-description が and が after quantified noun phrases, states that:

The generalization seems to be that when the subject contains a
numeral or a quantifier, it can be followed by descriptive ga even
if its predicate represents a stable state.

The emphasis on "can" is mine. To further explore this topic and see how well は does here, I would like to ask for a comparison of the following sentences featuring 多く and 大部分. I am not asking for a comparison of  set 1) with set 2), but rather for two independent comparisons of the sentences within set 1) and set 2).
1a) アメリカ人の多くが白人です。
1b) アメリカ人の多くは白人です。
1c) 多くのアメリカ人が白人です。
1d) 多くのアメリカ人は白人です。
2a) アメリカ人の大部分が白人です。
2b) アメリカ人の大部分は白人です。
2c) 大部分のアメリカ人が白人です。
2d) 大部分のアメリカ人は白人です。
Do all of these sentences sound natural? Are any of them strongly preferable in terms of how frequent their syntax is?
This is related to this question.


1a) アメリカ人の多くが白人です。
1b) アメリカ人の多くは白人です。
1c) 多くのアメリカ人が白人です。
1d) 多くのアメリカ人は白人です。

When writing a single sentence to simply state a fact without any context or implication, Sentence 1b) would be the best choice, followed by 1d). Sentence 1a) sounds like you're trying to vividly provide reasons or background information within some kind of narrative; it appears somewhat abrupt when viewed in isolation. This tendency is even stronger in Sentence 1c). It almost sounds to me as if it has "Remember" or "Importantly" prefixed to it.
All four sentences are suitable as catchphrases for a poster, but 1a) and 1c) may sound more dramatic and evoke some kind of story, while 1b) and 1d) might sound more matter-of-fact.
The same applies to 2a) through 2d).
(Note that this answer is based on my intuition as a native speaker, but I have no explicit knowledge of how this topic is treated in authoritative textbooks.)
